# mongoose findOne does not give the document even if it is there

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My query is as shown below:

```
const checkBook = (book_name) => {
    console.log("book name " + book_name);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Books.findOne({ 'Book': book_name }).then((info) => {
            if (!info) {
                console.log("no book");
                reject("there is no book");
            }
            console.log("book " + info);
            resolve(info);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("htytyyt" + err);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

Books.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Books = new Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    CurrentlyAvailableStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true // true --> book available false --> book not available
    }

}, {
    versionKey: false
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('books', Books);
```

Now,here my query gives me null result for `console.log("book" +info)`even if the document is there inside the database, what is wrong with that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying on incorrect field name

```
Books.findOne({ 'Book': book_name })
```

should be

```
Books.findOne({ Name: book_name })
```